# predict multivariate model using rfsrc

Tags: r, random-forest

I use the package "randomForestSRC" and I want to predict two variables at the same time. I have no issue predicting both of these variables alone, but can't get the combination to work. Here's a mwe:

```
library(randomForestSRC)

# create dataset, only continuous variables    
dat <- mtcars[,c("drat", "wt", "qsec")]
dat$drat_wt <- dat$drat*dat$wt
dat$drat_qsec <- dat$drat*dat$qsec
train <- sample(nrow(dat), round(nrow(dat)*0.8))

# train the algorithms with only one outcome variable
test_1 <- rfsrc(drat_wt ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                   importance = 'permute')
test_2 <- rfsrc(drat_qsec ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                importance = 'permute')
# train the radom forest with multiple outcome variables
test_3 <- rfsrc(cbind(drat_qsec,drat_wt) ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                importance = 'permute')
test_4 <- rfsrc(Multivar(drat_qsec,drat_wt) ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                importance = 'permute')

# predict all the random forest data
pred_1 <- predict(test_1, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
pred_2 <- predict(test_2, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
pred_3 <- predict(test_3, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
pred_4 <- predict(test_4, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
```

Now for the random forests with only one outcome (`pred_1` and `pred_2`) there is an index `pred_1$predicted` containing the predicted values, not however for the other random forests.

Bonus: Is there any difference in the `test_3` and `test_4` formulation? Couldn't find anything said on that in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, the output of pred_3 and pred_4 contain a list element, regrOutput, that is not contained in the pred_1 and pred_2 objects. If you look inside of this object, you will find the names of the two outcome (or target or dependent or ...) variables. For example,

```
names(pred_4$regrOutput)
[1] "drat_qsec" "drat_wt"
```

Now, inside each of these ojects, you find the objects that are missing in the 
`names(pred_1)`. For example,

```
names(pred_4$regrOutput$drat_qsec)
[1] "predicted"     "predicted.oob" "quantile"      "quantile.oob"  "err.rate"
```

and

```
setdiff(names(pred_1), names(pred_3))
[1] "predicted"     "predicted.oob" "quantile"      "quantile.oob"  "err.rate"
```

---

I am not sure about the second question, but the objects have the same structure. One way to explore this is to look through the objects.

For example, set the seed for each forest and then look at the returned objects.

```
set.seed(1234)
test_3 <- rfsrc(cbind(drat_qsec,drat_wt) ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                importance = 'permute')
set.seed(1234)
test_4 <- rfsrc(Multivar(drat_qsec,drat_wt) ~ . ,data = dat[train,],
                importance = 'permute')
```

Since the first element is the call, which we know is different, drop it and check for identity.

```
identical(test_3[-1], test_4[-1])
```

Now, look at each element in the returned objects.

```
mapply(identical, test_3, test_4)
```

Zero in on the those that are not identical:

```
which(!mapply(identical, test_3, test_4))
 call     forest regrOutput 
     1         19         36
```

Then further into the object...

```
which(!mapply(identical, test_3$forest, test_4$forest))
nativeArray 
          2
```

and so on.

However, what might matter most is, do these produce the same result? Let's rerun the prediction and taking a look at the predicted values.

```
pred_3 <- predict(test_3, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
pred_4 <- predict(test_4, dat[-train,], na.action= "na.impute")
```

Now, take a look

```
pred_3$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted
[1] 68.04419 55.95063 55.02067 56.38382 56.38382 75.33735
pred_4$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted
[1] 68.04419 55.95063 55.02067 56.38382 56.38382 75.33735
```

They look the same to me

```
identical(pred_3$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted,
          pred_4$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted)
[1] FALSE
```

They aren't identical, though. Let's use the recommended `all.equal` function to check for floating point values.

```
all.equal(pred_3$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted,
          pred_4$regrOutput$drat_qsec$predicted)
[1] TRUE
```

Ah, it's probably just a matter of numerical precision.

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at my question when you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684292/r-plot-individual-predictions thank you!